# Calling Java Method with variable length argument (varags) from jython

Tags: java, python, testing, jython

I'm trying to test some Java code with Jython, but I'm stuck with a constructor that uses the ... varags syntax.

I tried these:

```
MyConstructor(normal_arg, foo1, foo2)
MyConstructor(normal_arg, [foo1, foo2])
MyConstructor(normal_arg, array([foo1, foo2], footype))
```

But none of those worked (edit: sorry, nr. 2 and 3 do work!). How can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oooops, never mind. MyConstructor(normal_arg, [foo1, foo2]) actually worked and I misread an error in another line.